# Invalid argument exception: You must specify a WS or WSS scheme for the endpoint SessionId: 7ed77e0dfbe242f9bc8d51af42e536de

Tags: azure, service, speech-recognition

1. Hello ;
   I'm trying to use the speech-to-text with the recognition service in microsoft azure but i keep having
   this error :  Error details: Invalid argument exception: You must specify a WS or WSS scheme for the
   endpoint SessionId: 7ed77e0dfbe242f9bc8d51af42e536de

the code :

````
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioConfig


speech_key , endpoint ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" , "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key , endpoint=endpoint)


audio_config = AudioConfig(device_name="{0.0.0.00000000}.{6550a064-3849-40ab-af4f-2ffbb4e27b65}")
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

print("Say something...")

result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

# Checks result.
if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
    print("Recognized: {}".format(result.text))
elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
    print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(result.no_match_details))
elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
    cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
    print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
    if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
        print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))```
````

Comment: is it possible that it has something to do with my key and endpoint